# Custom Form Undefined Property

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I had a custom Module with **custom form**, which was working fine until recently.
Most likely it is throwing error after upgrade from 2.2.2 to 2.2.6.

and the line representing the error is like:

```
$templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
```

and the error shown is like this:

> Notice: Undefined property:
>   MyCompany\Mymodule\Controller\Index\Form\Interceptor::$storeManager in
>   /home/www/public_html/app/code/MyCompany/Mymodule/Controller/Index/Form.php
>   on line 113

is it related to upgrade or could it be something else.

The whole code of the class looks like this:

```
namespace MyCompany\Mymodule\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Form extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
/**
 * Contact action
 *
 * @return void
 */
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
 */

 /**
* @var Google reCaptcha Options
*/
private static $_siteVerifyUrl = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?";
private $_secret;
private static $_version = "php_7.0";
/**
* Save Form Data
*
* @return array
*/
protected $_transportBuilder;
protected $_storeManager;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,

   // \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
     \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
//  $this->fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;

    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    parent::__construct($context);

}

public function execute()
{

    $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    if (!empty($post)) {
        // Retrieve your form data
        $name   = $post['name'];
        $email  = $post['email'];
        $mobile  = $post['mobile'];
        $sku  = $post['sku'];
        $width  = $post['width'];
        $height  = $post['height'];
        $shipto  = $post['ship_to'];
        $remark = $post['remark'];
        $captcha = $this->getRequest()->getParam('g-recaptcha-response');

        $secret = "6LcjmUsUAAAAAM3ZNm02YjdW7tHqJetUqS2Q4J8f"; //Replace with your secret key
        $response = null;
        $path = self::$_siteVerifyUrl;
        $dataC = array (
        'secret' => $secret,
        'remoteip' => $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        'v' => self::$_version,
        'response' => $captcha
        );
        $req = "";
        foreach ($dataC as $key => $value) {
             $req .= $key . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
        }
        // Cut the last '&'
        $req = substr($req, 0, strlen($req)-1);
        $response = file_get_contents($path . $req);
       //var_dump($response);exit;
        $answers = json_decode($response, true);
        //var_dump($answers);exit;
        if(trim($answers ['success']) == true) {


        $MyCompany = $this->_objectManager->create('MyCompany\Mymodule\Model\MyCompany');

        $MyCompany->setName($name);
        $MyCompany->setMobile($mobile);
        $MyCompany->setEmail($email);
        $MyCompany->setSku($sku);
        $MyCompany->setWidth($width);
        $MyCompany->setHeight($height);
        $MyCompany->setShip_to($shipto);
        $MyCompany->setRemarks($remark);
        $MyCompany->save();

        //$this->getResponse()->setBody('Your Request is Submitted Successfully !');

        // Doing-something with...

        // Display the succes form validation message
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Your Request is Submitted Successfully !');
        }else{
     $this->messageManager->addError(__('Captcha Validation Failed. Please retry')
                             );

}


         $templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
      //  var_dump($templateOptions);exit;

        $templateVars = array(
               'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(),
                'customer_name' => $name,
                'mobile' => $mobile,
                'email' => $email,
                'width' => $width,
                'height' => $height,
                'shipto' => $shipto,
                'remark'   => $remark
            );
        $from = array('email' => "contact@mycompany.com", 'name' => 'Indian Art Zone');
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $to = array($email,'sales@mycompany.com');
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('MyCompany_email_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->addTo($to)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

        // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl('/MyCompany/index/form');

        return $resultRedirect;
    }
    // Render the page
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
}
```

}

Comment: Show me please class MyCompany/Mymodule/Controller/Index/Form.php

Comment: please defined store manager in controller.

Comment: did you find your solution?